# How is it possible to have more sessions than users for a given period of time in Azure Application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In the Azure Application Insights Usage module I can see I have had more sessions than users in the last 24 hours. How is this possible? Is it because when a session expires after 30m of inactivity and a new one is created it gets the same user id as the expired one? I just want to be sure . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

**What's a session?**

A session represents a single encounter between the user and the app. In its simplest form, session starts with a user launching the app and finishes when user leaves the app. For web apps, by default, the session terminates after 30 minutes of inactivity, or after 24 hours of activity.

**Users and user counts**

Each user session is associated with a unique user id.

By default, the user is identified by placing a cookie. A user who uses multiple browsers or devices will be counted more than once. (But see authenticated users)

**The user count** metric in a certain interval is defined as the number of unique users with recorded activity during this interval. As a result, users with long sessions may be accounted multiple times, when you set a time range so that the grain is less than an hour or so.

**New Users** counts the users whose first sessions with the app occurred during this interval. If the default method of counting by users by cookies is used, then this will also include users who have cleared their cookies, or who are using a new device or browser to access your app for the first time.

More info can be read here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/

Comment: If a user has a long session he will be accounted multiple times but the session just one time? It seems that in this case I'll end up with more users than sessions (if a bunch of my users have long sessions).

Comment: A user is accounted for one session (within the 30min inactive and 24hours active, unless they delete their cookies. So, you would have at times, most likely, more sessions than users at one time, based on how long a user stays active.